# Extracting the number of digits in a macro constant at compile-time

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I need to do some preprocessor magic. Assume that I have a global constant

```
#define MAX_VALUE 99999
```

What I need to do is to extract the length of this constant in its decimal representation at compile-time. In other words, I don't want to have another constant

```
#define MAX_VALUE_STRLEN 5
```

polluting the global namespace and I don't want to add a place in the code that needs to be changed in the case that MAX_VALUE is modified. If I have a number literal, then I can do something like

```
#define INTLEN(x) (sizeof(#x)/sizeof((#x)[0]) - 1)
```

and then `INTLEN(99999)` would expand to `5` at compile-time. Unfortunately, I can't do something like

```
INTLEN(MAX_VALUE),
```

because the preprocessor expands INTLEN first, so that I get

```
 (sizeof("MAX_VALUE")/sizeof(("MAX_VALUE")[0]) - 1)
```

Is there a preprocessor trick that achieves what I want? Another trickier issue that I should be able to safely ignore is that can this be made generic enough that if someone decides to add a type annotation, say, 99999L to the constant that I can still get the right value?

Comment: You can use the `#` character to stringify a macro. Use two levels of indirection to stringify the expansion of the macro.

Comment: Can you define things the other way round, such that `MAX_VALUE_STRLEN` drives `MAX_VALUE`?

Comment: the constants are POSIX constants from system headers, so I can't go changing them

Comment: What happens for:  <code>#define MAX_VALUE (99999)</code>?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stringify using `#` and two levels of macro expansion, then chop off the terminating `NUL`:

```
#define MAX_VALUE 99999

#define STRINGIFY(x) #x

#define LENGTH(x) (sizeof(STRINGIFY(x)) - 1)

#include <stdio.h>    

int main()
{
    size_t n = LENGTH(MAX_VALUE);
    printf("length = %zu\n", n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @WeatherVane not my fault. `size_t` is conventionally used for sizes (and it's what the `sizeof` operator yields anyway). The `%zu` conversion specifier is present in C99 and later; too bad MSVC doesn't support C99.

Comment: I'm on MSVC 9.0 anyway - the freebie.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the  `#define STRINGIFY_` is not being used... or am I missing something?

Comment: Nope, it's not used. However, it's a very cool trick (although not needed  here) to add one more level of expansion to a function, so that the argument can be made to expand first. Thanks!

Comment: @EdvardFagerholm oops, indeed, it's not used. it's not necessary, I've removed it (since you already have the needed levels of indirection).